# MYSQL Query fails on Left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in fight with an sql query i cant seem to figure out, and hope somebody might help me with this.

I got two tables i want to have connected together. My first table is the 'achievement' table, which has 3 fields: achievementId, AchievementName and ZoneId

My second table is a table that is in between my User and this achivement table, which stores basically also 3 items. The UserId, AchievementId and IsChecked. It refers here to a checkbox.

So I am working on a page that shows all the achievements in the form of a checkbox list, so I want to have those who are already achieved to be shown in the list, however, the query i am trying to get fails completely and I have no idea how to fix it. I tried the below item, but off course I failed miserable. So I was hoping if you guys could help me out here and adjust my query.

My current query is

```
Select * from Achievement
Where Zone = '2'
LEFT JOIN  Achievement_User
    Where Achievement_User.UserId='2'
    And Achievement_User.AchievementId = Achievement.AchievementId
```

but it fails off course. I probably have the syntax wrong, but I cant figure it out. If somebody could help me out?

**EDIT** I think i explained this wrong. But the left join shows only the ones that match, however, I need the full list of the achievement, which is like 40 rows, it only shows now the rows where there is data from the Achievement_User with the query supplied by @Aquillo. I prefer ot have all 40 rows supplied by the Achivements with zone 2

Comment: You forgot the ON condition.

Comment: Whats the purpose of left joining if the outer table userID = 2?

Comment: @Dan because he is joining on AchievementId, not UserId

Comment: @Aquillo Left joining, but then requiring the value in UserID = '2' essentially makes it an inner join, no?

Comment: @Dan yes you're right, except for the rare case where there wouldn't be a User with ID 2.

Comment: @Dorvalla, in response to your update i've removed the last row of my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have two WHERE-clauses, secondly a JOIN is a JOIN ON. Try this:

```
Select * 
from Achievement
LEFT JOIN  Achievement_User ON Achievement_User.AchievementId = Achievement.AchievementId
Where Zone = '2'
```

**Update in response to OP's update**

In that case you shouldn't use a restriction on the UserID, try the above query.